# Android: Animate text from one TextView to another

Tags: android, animation, textview

As an Android beginner, I'm trying to re-program the standard **Huawei calculator app**. I would like to try to keep as closely as possible to this app in all respects.

Now I am faced with the problem that I do not know how to implement the animation from the result of the calculation below (probably a `TextView` field) to the calculation text (an `EditText` field, because that's where you enter the calculation).

That you can imagine better what I mean, here a screenshot, and a GIF with the mentioned animation:

[image: Screenshot of the calculator with the calculation above and the result below]

[image: GIF of the animation]

I've tried it already with the `TextSwitcher` class but this doesn't work because you can only use one `TextView` there and also you can't use `EditText` fields.

I hope you can help me and I look forward to every answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

On equal clickListener, you have to add some animation to this.

Find below code:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
            slideUp.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // Update the text here

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            llContainer.startAnimation(slideUp);

        }
    });
```

Create `anim` folder within `res` folder and add file `slide_up.xml` and below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Archana! In the code I have replaced llContainer with my TextView. Is that correct? Now I have an animation that goes up, but I actually wanted my text to go from the lower TextView to the upper EditText and at the same time the text of this EditText which disappears upwards. So my main problem is that I don't know how to bring the lower text from the TextView into the upper EditText with a transition animation like in the GIF.

Comment: Give an animation to editText itself at the end of animation I.e `onAnimationEnd()`, Update the editText value with the textView value.